# Bazel genrule: how to get absolute path to workspace directory?

Tags: git, bazel, bazel-rules

I want to create a bazel gen-rule to create a header file that contains the current git commit hash:

```
# Generate "version_info.h"
cc_library(
    name = "version_info",
    srcs = [],
    hdrs = ["version_info.h"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)

VERSION_INFO_H_BASH = """
#ifndef VERSION_INFO_H_
#define VERSION_INFO_H_

#define COMMIT_HASH "%s"

#endif  // VERSION_INFO_H_
"""

VERSION_INFO_H_PS = """
#ifndef VERSION_INFO_H_
#define VERSION_INFO_H_

#define COMMIT_HASH "{0}"

#endif  // VERSION_INFO_H_
"""

genrule(
    name = "generate_version_info",
    outs = ["version_info.h"],
    cmd_ps = ("cd what_comes_here; @'%s'@ -f \"$$(git.exe rev-parse HEAD)\" | Out-File $(OUTS)" % VERSION_INFO_H_PS),
    cmd = ("cd what_comes_here"; printf '%s' \"$$(git rev-parse HEAD)\ > $(OUTS)" % VERSION_INFO_H_BASH),
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)
```

So far I haven't tested the linux version (cmd) but only on windows (cmd_ps) and it works, but the problem is that when powershell executes, it's not in the workspace directory (which is my git root). What do I need to replace `what_comes_here` with to first cd into the root of my workspace?

Comment: Bazel runs builds on a server machine (not necessarily yours), in a sandbox that is—at least ideally—isolated from the host. It seems that there would be no guarantee that there *is* a Git repository from which to rev-parse `HEAD`. Perhaps you have some additional build bits that help guarantee this?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the [workspace status](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#workspace_status) feature of Bazel. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/JulianSchmid/example-bazel-add-git-hash).

Comment: that seems overly complex, I don't wanna have to write an external program for that - I just need the absolute path of the workspace so that I can cd into it before calling git

Comment: My issue with this solution is that it requires users to do something special (ie use `bazel --workspace_status_command=`)